# How do I use a simple button in a co-ordinator layout such that the button hides on scroll down and shows up on scroll up?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I wanted to have a simple button inside a co-ordinator layout such that when I scroll down the nested scrollview the button musy hide and on scrolling up I must be able to view the button again. How do I achieve that. I googled a lot, but I got stuffs relevant to floating button, I am not using the floatingactionbutton. I am using the simple Button. So, how do I achieve my aim? Please help me out guys!
Regards, 
Thanks.

Comment: do you want a callback of scrolling end point (top and bottom) ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did not get you. I have created a layout with collapsing toolbar and also a button that remains at the bottom of that page throughout the layout. But what I need now is, to make that button only visible on scroll up.